# How to filter by material e.g. walls of concrete or steel

Tags: autodesk-forge

I use a large revit file and when I access the properties via`getProperties(id)`.
Is there a best practice way of filtering by property, because it is causing performance issues?
My approach:

```
      /**
   * Looks inside the Autodesk-Database for the material category and looks if the material is concrete.
   * Returns asynchronously an array with all ids which represent parts built with concrete material
   * @returns {Promise<Array | void>}
   */
  async getConcreteIds() {
    const wallfloorids = await this.getWallFloorIds()
    let concreteIds = []
    let filterCategory = 'Materialien und Oberflächen'
    let filterValue = 'Concrete'
    let promises = wallfloorids.map(id => {
      let p1 = this.getProperties(id)
      return p1
        .then((props) => {
          console.log(props)
          for (let prop of props) {
            let filtercondition =
              prop.displayCategory === filterCategory &&
              prop.displayValue.contains(filterValue)
            if (filtercondition) {
              concreteIds.push(id)
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
    return Promise.all(promises)
      .then( concreteIds)
      .catch(err => console.log('Err', err))
  }

  /**
   * acquires properties of a part out of Autodesk Database
   * @param dbId
   * @returns {Promise<any>}
   */
  getProperties(dbId): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.viewer.getProperties(
        dbId,
        args => {
          resolve(args.properties)
        },
        reject
      )
    })

  }
```

This worked until recently when I used a small file, since the small file did not have as many properties and dbIds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function called `Viewer3D#search` which can to be used to search property with specific value:

```
viewer.search('Concrete', 
   function(dbIds) {
      console.log( dbIds );
   },
   function( error ) {
      console.error( error )
   },
   ['Structural Material']
);
```

Or you can use `Viewer3D#getBulkProperties` to obtain lots of properties of given `dbIds` that match passed property names:

```
viewer.model.getBulkProperties(dbIds, ['Structural Material'],
   function(elements){
     let dbIds = [];
     let filterCategory = "Materials and Finishes";
     let filterValue = 'Concrete';

     for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
       const prop = elements[i].properties[0];
       const dbId = elements[i].dbId;
       if(prop.displayCategory === filterCategory && prop.displayValue.contains(filterValue)) {
         dbIds.push( dbId );
       }
     }
     console.log(dbIds);
   });
```

Check her for references:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/getbulkproperties-method
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/search-method-performance
- https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Both of them always return undefined or do not log anything. What can I do?

Comment: Where returns undefined? Can you describe more specifically? Snapshots, code snippets, and screencasts are all helpful.

Comment: I use this    ` this.viewer.search('"Concrete"',
      function(dbIds) {
        console.log( dbIds );
      },
      function( error ) {
        console.error( error )
      },
      ['Materialien und Oberflächen']
    ); `

Due to the weird nature of my revit file i need to look for Material and Finishes in german.

This is a working example but much much slower https://imgur.com/a/UkGJVx8

The above code does not log any dbids, also tried with different properties

Comment: There are two unexpected symbols `'"Concrete"'` here, it should be `"Concrete"` or `'Concrete'`. This might be the reason why it didn't work on your side.

Comment: the link you sent me  encourages this way of writing the search text https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/search-method-performance.
Putting in ['name'] instead of ['Structural Material'] returns an array which does not contain the correct ids. not inputting an attribute name gives me an array which contains the correct ids among a lot of unwanted ones

Comment: I guess due to the inconsistency of my models properties I cannot seem to find them so easily by looking at materials, but thank you. When inputting an attribute name such as name it easily finds elements and when not inputting an attribute name it just gives everything with the search text in it